# MVC 5, show data by group in Index page

Tags: asp.net, group-by

I'm new in MVC5.
I have 2 table, `tblClient` & `tblBranch`.
The Data Structure are:

### tblClient

```
ID | Name
---------
1  | BCS
2  | LBBI
3  | CARB
```

### tblBranch

```
ID | cID | BranchName
---------------------
1  | 1   | Savar
2  | 1   | Nobinogor
3  | 2   | Sawrapara
4  | 1   | Mirpur
5  | 3   | Motijheel
6  | 2   | Dhanmondi
7  | 1   | Kazipara
```

Now I need to show data in index page as like:

### BCS

```
sL | Branch
-----------
1  | Savar
2  | Nobinogor
3  | Mirpur
4  | Kazipara
```

### LBBI

```
sL | Branch
-----------
1  | Sawrapara
2  | Dhanmondi
```

### CARB

```
sL | Branch
-----------
1  | Motijheel
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why use such boldy text? Its not easy to read now!

Answer (score 1):

Write a model class for your index view.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string GroupName;
    public List<string> GroupItems;
}
```

Specify your model for your view:

```
@model IEnumurable<MyProject.MyModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h2>@item.GroupName</h2>
    <ol>
    @foreach (var it in item.GroupItems)
    {
       <li>@it</li>
    }
    </ol>
}
```

And finally in the index action of your controller fill the model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new List<MyModel>();
    var item = new MyModel();
    item.GroupName = "Hello World";
    item.GroupItems = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2" };
    model.Add(item);
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap every tblClient in new Object:

```
tblClient has name and contains List of tblBranch

public Class Client
{
public string clientName {get;set;}
public List<Branch> branches {get;set;}
}

public Class Branch
{
public string branchName
}
```

and retriere `List<Client>` and show them to the UI

Comment: I'm new user, Please explain more.

Comment: @MarufHossain: you don't know how retrieve data from db to c# or you don't know how to use razor synthax to show data in the UI ?

Comment: @MarufHossain could you respond please?

Comment: I'm new that's why I'm not use to with RAZOR syntax. But I've solved it in another way though it is not the right way.

I'm using view to retrieve data and show data. Now I'm trying to use model and insert data from controller and show data in view.

Comment: @Maruf View just show data, controller handle user actions (new page, button clicked, ...) and "send" the things to do (for instance delete one record, show list of something, ...) to another classes (for instance a layer that you call DataAccessLayer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in doing something unusual. Especially, groupping by.
You can simply iterate through items and output it.

In ASP.NET Razor:

```
Dictionary<int, string> clients = // get dictionary from DB like {{1, "BCS"}, {2, "LBBI"} ...}};
List<BranchEntity> branches = // get list of Branch entities just like in DB;
// You can pass these values as ViewBag or together as a Model

@{
    foreach (var client in clients)
    {
        var branchesForClients = branches.Where(x => x.cID == client.Key).ToArray();

        <h3>@client.Value</h3>
        <table>
        for (int i = 0; i < branchesForClients.Length; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@(i + 1)</td>
                <td>@branchesForClients[i].BranchName</td>
            </tr>
        }    
        </table>
    }
}
```

Here is an entity:

```
public class BranchEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int cId { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
}
```